# Regex result not show up in C#?

Tags: c#

I tried to parsing query from google that comming to mysite but its not showing up, but according http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx, and with regex buddy, my regex was right. But when I tried its with live development its not showing up....

Its the string that I want to parse:

```
imgurl=http://www.blabla.com/products/W7i5W4Pw4fH22Mih/P_500.jpg&q=ASUS+Rampage+II+Extreme+LGA1366+Intel+X58+DDR3-1600+ATX+Motherboard&imgrefurl=http://www.blabla.com/Mboards/Intel/Rampage_II_Extreme/&usg=__4HSriQuFeVXg5AWsOGlZlsAmMmg=&h=500&w=500&sz=37&hl=en&start=1&zoom=1&tbnid=9ImqgVuzVz5ThM:&tbnh=130&tbnw=130&ei=MKrYUNm9MI6zrAfWi4GQBw&um=1&itbs=1&ptbm=isch
```

And here my code.

```
string Website = url; //url
string regularExpressionPattern = @"&q=(.*?)&imgrefurl";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(Website, regularExpressionPattern);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Even with debugger its not result? 
NB: I using Microsoft Visual C# 2008, windows xp 2

Comment: I can't reproduce. There is one match with the expected group having the value `ASUS+Rampage+II+Extreme+LGA1366+Intel+X58+DDR3-1600+ATX+Motherboard`.

Comment: I second Oded's comment. I just ran this code and got the same result.

Comment: Yes, but In my Microsoft Visual C# 2008 not showing up? is there any issue about this?

Comment: Is there other code you have around this that maybe is causing the problem. Like maybe the url gets reset, or you clear your regex, or something else. Three people have not tested your code and all have received the same result, so there is probably something else going on. Meaning, the problem is apparently not in this snippet of code.

Comment: Use `(?<=&q=).*?(?=&imgrefurl)`. It yields the result directly: `m.Value`. It uses the general pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)`.

Comment: @all

thank for your kindness, I already found the answers... Finally I can sleep now... but Why its adding **amp;** after &?

Comment: It's not adding `amp;` after `&`. It's representing `&` by `&amp;` the same way you would represent a non breaking space with `&nbsp;`. `amp` means ampersand. There are many of them: `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>`, `&auml;` for `ä` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me:

[image: screenshot of program run]

I suspect that the string does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: thanks for you advice, its just like you said, its got some weird **amp** characters in url

Comment: @radiaku: You mean `&amp;`? That's called a character entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my own answers...

When I use HttpWebRequest to downloading into my apps its adding **amp;** after **&**

so the url looking like this...

```
imgurl=http://www.blabla.com/products/W7i5W4Pw4fH22Mih/P_500.jpg&amp;q=ASUS+Rampage+II+Extreme+LGA1366+Intel+X58+DDR3-1600+ATX+Motherboard&amp;imgrefurl=http://www.blabla.com/Mboards/Intel/Rampage_II_Extreme/&amp;usg=__4HSriQuFeVXg5AWsOGlZlsAmMmg=&amp;h=500&amp;w=500&amp;sz=37&amp;hl=en&amp;start=1&amp;zoom=1&amp;tbnid=9ImqgVuzVz5ThM:&amp;tbnh=130&amp;tbnw=130&amp;ei=MKrYUNm9MI6zrAfWi4GQBw&amp;um=1&amp;itbs=1&amp;ptbm=isch
```

Its weird?